# Авто обновляема таблица из API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, api

Задача сделать таблицу, с данными из api (https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=BTC_ETH)

Так же нужно чтоб данные обновлялись автоматически без обновления страницы.
Не могу придумать как это реализовать

Comment: загрузить извне, сформировать таблицу, отдать пользователю, что тут думать?

Comment: `setInterval + ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<table id="table-list">
 <tr>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>GlobalTradeID</th>
  <th>TradeID</th>
  <th>orderNumber</th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Rate</th>
  <th>Total</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```

```js
function loadData() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTradeHistory&currencyPair=BTC_ETH',
      type: 'GET',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      error: function(req, text, error) {
          alert(error);
      },
      success: function ( data ) {
          if ( data && $.isArray(data) && data.length > 0 ) {
              $('#table-list tr:not(:eq(0))').remove();
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  $('#table-list tr:last-child').after('<tr>' +
                      '<td>' + data[i].type+'</td>'+
                      '<td>' + data[i].globalTradeID+'</td>'+
                      '<td>' + data[i].tradeID+'</td>'+
                      '<td>' + data[i].orderNumber+'</td>'+
                      '<td>' + data[i].date+'</td>'+
                      '<td>' + data[i].rate+'</td>'+
                      '<td>' + data[i].total+'</td>'+
                      '</tr>');
              }
          }
      },
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
      loadData();
    }, <кол-во секунд через которое произойдет обновление>);

});
```